# [TablePagination-MUI]: Missing form label accessibility issue in Wave tool

Tags: material-ui, accessibility

"Missing form label" accessibility issue in Wave tool when using Table pagination. How do I fix it.

```js
<TablePagination
      ref={paginationComponentRef}
      ActionsComponent={PaginationActionsComponent}
      component='div'
      page={page}
      rowsPerPageOptions={5, 10, 25]}
      rowsPerPage={0}
      intl={props.intl}
      count={props.count || 0}
      onChangePage={props.onChangePage || handleChangePage}
      onChangeRowsPerPage={props.onChangeRowsPerPage || handleChangeRowsPerPage}
      backIconButtonProps={{
        'aria-label': props.intl.formatMessage(messages.prev, props.customTexts),
      }}
      nextIconButtonProps={{
        'aria-label': props.intl.formatMessage(messages.next, props.customTexts),
      }}
    />
```

output rendered html:

```html
<div class="MuiInputBase-root MuiTablePagination-input MuiTablePagination-selectRoot">
<div class="MuiSelect-root MuiSelect-select MuiTablePagination-select MuiSelect-selectMenu MuiInputBase-input" tabindex="0" role="button" aria-haspopup="listbox" aria-labelledby="mui-8736 mui-43" id="mui-43">5</div><input aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1" class="MuiSelect-nativeInput" value="5"><svg class="MuiSvgIcon-root MuiSelect-icon MuiTablePagination-selectIcon" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true"><path d="M7 10l5 5 5-5z"></path>
</svg></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to change the pagination select design then use this

```js
SelectProps={{
  inputProps: {
    'aria-label': 'rows per page',
    'aria-labelledby': 'rowsPage',
  },
  id: 'rowsPage',
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the below code in your `<TablePagination />` tag.

```
SelectProps={{
            inputProps: { 'aria-label': 'rows per page' },
            native: true,
            }}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It works like cherry on top of cake.

Comment: When you add native: true in SelectProps you will get cross browser issue in Firefox browser(All the list items in the native select will be left aligned). So it is better to use normal Select only.